# Cisco ASA: How can I use an enhanced service list in an access-list rule?

Tags: firewall, cisco, cisco-asa

On a Cisco ASA 5505, software version 8.0.4, how can I use an enhanced service list in an access rule?

```
object-group service MY-SERVICES 
 description ports to allow through firewall for sitecore
 service-object tcp www
 service-object tcp https
 service-object tcp ssh
 service-object icmp echo
 service-object icmp echo-reply
exit
```

When I try to use it I get the  following:

```
access-list inside_access_in extended permit ip object-group NETWORK1 object-group  NETWORK2   object-group MY_SERVICES
                                                                                               ^
ERROR: % Invalid Hostname
```

What is the syntax needed to use an extended service list (which includes multiple protocols, TCP and ICMP in this case) in an acces-list rule?  The [Cisco example](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/hw/vpndevc/ps2030/products_tech_note09186a00800d641d.shtml#serv) only shows it being used in a basic access list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your object-group mix icmp and tcp so you can't place it at the end of the access-list where a port number is generally placed.
Try to put your object group at the place where you put 'ip'

like:

```
access-list inside_access_in extended permit object-group MY_SERVICES object-group NETWORK1 object-group NETWORK2
```